# Are theorems, lemmas etc as new paragraphs or as in a paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs

Curious about skips above and below them and the indentation.

Answer (score 4):

opinions differ on this matter.

`amsthm` treats each theorem-class object as a separate unit, beginning and ending with a paragraph break.  depending on the `\theoremstyle` (three are predefined), there may or may not be extra space above or below.  the text that starts immediately after a theorem-class object is always assumed to start a new paragraph, and unless that is overridden, it will be indented; this is true whether or not a blank line is present (but for ease of reading the input file, a blank line *is* recommended.)

the same paragraphing convention is true for the `proof` environment of `amsthm`; however, here there is also the extra visual cue of the "tombstone" at the end, as well as extra space above and below.

for details, have a look at the `amsthm` user's guide -- `texdoc amsthm`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `amsthm` package. It provides commands and environments for typesetting all kinds of theorems.
Also the spaces above and below a paragraph will be set.